# Why i see x509: certificate signed by unknown authority?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Can you tell me how to fix the problem with certificates?

Here is a piece of my GITLAB_CI config:
[image: .gitlab-ci.yml]

When I click on package-build-core-ci job:
[image: pipelines jobs]

Job fails:
[image: package-build-core-ci job log]

i tried duplicating the command which is added in before_script:

- `cp /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/*.crt .`
- `update-ca-certificates`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Add registry domains certificate as `/etc/docker/certs.d/<YOUR_REGISTRY_DOMAIN_NAME>/ca.crt` for docker.

```
mkdir -p /etc/docker/certs.d/example.com
cp example.com.crt /etc/docker/certs.d/example.com/ca.crt
```